# JQuery, can't draw collabsable tree list

Tags: jquery, html, json, treeview

I have an Issue. I am using JQuery, to get a JSON nested list of objects. I go through it and can read all my data and evrything is fine. But, when I try to get the result as a tree collapsible list using `$(#myDiv).html(value)`, it is not working. This function does create a try view but not collapsible. When I take the same result and create it as HTML, it works fine. In addition to the function `$(#myDiv).html(value)`, I also tried using `$(#myDiv).append(value)` and innerHTML. But it didn't help, I have the feeling that collapsible trees can not be implemented via these functions, or am I doing something wrong?

I am using this JavaScript Library and CSS to realize this:

http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/mktree/index.php

My Code:

```js
 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Set plus sign for all sub menus
            $('li:has("ul")>div').html('&plus;');

            //Handle plus/minus tree expansion
            $('li>div').on('click', function (e) {
                if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('selected')) {
                    $(this).siblings('ul').slideUp();
                    $(this).parent('li').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).html('&plus;');
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings('ul').slideDown();
                    $(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
                    $(this).html('&minus;')
                }
            })

            //Handle tree item link stored as LI data attribute
            $('li>label').on('click', function (e) {
                //This is your URL, URI, Link, Location, etc
                alert($(this).parent('li').attr('data-location'))
            })

        });
    </script>



<script type="text/javascript">

                var uri = 'InfoCenter.asmx/getAllRemoteAndLocal';

                $(document).ready(function () {


                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'InfoCenter.asmx/getAllRemoteAndLocal',
                        data: JSON.stringify(), //Pass a parameter to the Web Service method
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (ws_result) {
                            processResult(ws_result.d);
                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            alert("error msg: " + msg);
                        }
                    });


                });

                function processResult(msg) {

                    var resultArray = msg.split(" #*§$%# ");
                    var t = "";

                    for (i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
                        var sdRootStatus = eval("(" + resultArray[i] + ")");
                        //alert(resultArray[i]);
                        console.log(sdRootStatus);
                        //jQuery.each(data, function (rec) {
                        $.each(sdRootStatus, function (key, nodeStatus) {
                            var areaStatis = nodeStatus.areaStatis;

                            $.each(areaStatis, function (key, areaStatus) {
                                var areaObject = areaStatus.area;

                                t = t + "<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"expandTree('area" + areaObject.id + "');return false;\"> <img src=\"\Sources\\down.png\" class=\"small\"> </a>"
                                        + "<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"collapseTree('area" + areaObject.id + "'); return false;\">"
                                        + "<img src=\"\Sources\\up.png\" class=\"small\"> [all] </a>";

                                //t = t + "<div id=\"tree\"><ul>"
                                t = t + "<ul class=\"mktree\" id=\"area" + areaObject.id + "\">"
                                        //+ "<li> <img src=\"\Sources\\plus.gif\"/> " + areaObject.name + " <img src=\"\Sources\\" + getIcon(document.getElementById('emptyForm'), areaStatus.Color, 'global') + "\" class=\"global\">";
                                        + "<li>" + areaObject.name + " <img src=\"\Sources\\" + getIcon(document.getElementById('emptyForm'), areaStatus.Color, 'global') + "\" class=\"global\">";
                                var zonesStatis = areaStatus.zoneStatis;
                                $.each(zonesStatis, function (key, zoneStatus) {
                                    var zone = zoneStatus.zone;
                                    t = t + "<ul>"
                                            + "<li>" + zone.name + " <img src=\"\Sources\\" + getIcon(document.getElementById('emptyForm'), zoneStatus.Color, 'check') + "\" class=\"check\">";

                                    var componentStatis = zoneStatus.componentStatis;
                                    $.each(componentStatis, function (key, componentStatus) {
                                        var component = componentStatus.component;

                                        t = t + "<ul>"
                                                + "<li>" + component.ServiceName + " <img src=\"\Sources\\" + getIcon(document.getElementById('emptyForm'), componentStatus.Color, 'check') + "\" class=\"check\">";

                                        var checkAgentStatis = componentStatus.checkAgentStatis;

                                        $.each(checkAgentStatis, function (key, checkAgentStatus) {
                                            t = t + "<ul>"

                                                    + "<li title=\"" + checkAgentStatus.Description + "\" class=\"silver\">" + checkAgentStatus.Name + " <img src=\"\Sources\\" + getIcon(document.getElementById('emptyForm'), checkAgentStatus.Color, 'check') + "\" class=\"check\">"
                                                    + "</li></ul>";


                                        });

                                        t = t + "</li></ul>";

                                    });
                                    t = t + "</li></ul>";
                                });
                                t = t + "</li></ul></div>";
                            });

                        });
                    }


                    console.log(t);
                   $("#myDiv").html(t);

                    
                   //$("#myDiv").append(t);
                    //myDiv.innerHTML = t;
                }

</script>
```

```css
   <style type="text/css">
        div#tree ul {
            margin: 0 0 0 20px;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        div#tree ul {
            display: none;
        }

        div#tree li > div {
            display: inline;
            margin-right: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        div#tree label:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        div#tree > ul {
            display: block;
        }

        .large {
            color: #00FF00;
            font-family: arial;
            font-size: 4pt;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Main.aspx.cs" Inherits="SystemDiagnostics.Main" %>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript" src="./Sources/customUtils.js"></script>
<script src="./Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Sources/mktree.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Sources/mktree.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Sources/style.css">



 
</head>

<body>


    <div id="myDiv">

    </div>


  
    <form Action = "TestJSonClient.aspx" runat="server">

    </form>

    <form Action="#" id="emptyForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="green" value="<%=GREEN %>"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="yellow" value="<%=YELLOW %>"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="red" value="<%=RED %>"> 

            <input type="hidden" name="statusIconGreen" value="<%=STATUS_ICON_GREEN %>"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="statusIconYellow" value="<%=STATUS_ICON_YELLOW %>"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="statusIconRed" value="<%=STATUS_ICON_RED %>">

            <input type="hidden" name="statusCheckIconGreen" value="<%=CHECK_ICON_GREEN %>"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="statusCheckIconYellow" value="<%=CHECK_ICON_YELLOW %>"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="statusCheckIconRed" value="<%=CHECK_ICON_RED %>">
         
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do people use all these obscure libraries? For every little thing they want to do, they include a new one it seems :/

Comment: @OleSauffaus, I think your comment would be more useful if you recommended a non "obscure" alternative.  Either way, you're not helping to answer the question. Although I agree with avoiding "obscure" libraries when possible.

Comment: @Marc. Sorry ... just a rant ... nothing personal :) I don’t think I can help you.

Comment: problem likely lies in library expecting the markup to exist on page load. Don't use scripts that aren't well documented

Comment: Your code snippet isn't working, I guess its using ASP.NET. But there are a lot of libs out there that can help. I've had success with http://www.jstree.com

Comment: You can try jstree - it is not obscure, but it is a lot more complex.

Comment: Hi Vincent, Thanks for your answer, yes I am using ASP.NET. I am calling a WebService using JSon and trying to present the result as a collabsable tree using JQuery and HTML. I will try the recommended library jstree.com!

Comment: Hi Vakata, I used jstree as you Guys recommended, it is working fine, but only for one tree. I usually get a nested JSon object and would like to present it on the GUI. There are multiple Trees, which shall be presented in multiple "DIVs", which have to be created dynamically within the page Loading time. How can I get jstree create and work with Multiple trees? Thanks in advance!